# document.getElementById works with <> but not &It; &gt;

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am using a server side script to change a table on the client side request without refreshing the page. The text that comes for the server side is consistent and working but sometimes it never changes the output display on the client side. I put the prompts in to help troubleshoot.

When the code fails, the first prompt returns `<img src='anim.gif' class='pic'>` and the third returns with the `&It` and `&gt` replacing `<` and `>`. When the code works the first prompt returns `<img src='anim.gif' class='pic'>` and third has all `<` and `>` (instead of `&It` and `&gt`). I understand `&It/&gt` is a substitute for `<>`, but why would this work with one and not the other.

The second prompt with the table built by the server side script always returns a results with `<>`

To eliminate potential errors in the PHP generating the initial page, I copied the generated HTML and used it and got the same random success and failure.

I did not include the script that calls for the tables due to process of elimination and troubleshooting. The only difference produced by the other functions is the changes listed.

This is the script requesting the information:

```
function useHttpResponse2(){
    if (http2.readyState == 4){
        if(http2.status == 200){
            var temp = document.getElementById("left").innerHTML;
            prompt(temp ,temp);
            temp = http2.responseText;
            prompt(temp ,temp);
            document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = http2.responseText;
            temp = document.getElementById("left").innerHTML;
            prompt(temp ,temp);

        }
    }else{
        document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "<img src='anim.gif' class='pic'>";
    }
}
```

This is the page itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE htmls)
<html>
<style>
.right {
     float: left;
     width: 33%;
}
.middle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}
.left {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
}.pic {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    max-height: 325px;
    }
.table {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}
</style>
<head>
<script src='ArtFollow.js'></script>
<script src='Ajax.js'></script>
<script src='ArtPortfolio.js'></script>
<script type'text/javascript>var IDS = ["3","2","1"];</script>
<title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body background='img/marb009.jpg' onload="view_pics(IDS,'right', '3')">
<div class='right' id='right'><img src='anim.gif' class='pic'></div>
<div class='middle' id='middle'><img src='anim.gif' class='pic'></div>
<div class='left' id='left'><img src='anim.gif' class='pic'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: If a <div>, <span>, or <noembed> node has a child text node that includes the characters (&), (<), or (>), innerHTML returns these characters as &amp, &lt and &gt respectively. Use Node.textContent to get a correct copy of these text nodes' contents.

Comment: Since I was loading three pictures and only one failed and the location was always the same, I started to moving the function call orders and the div load order to see how the problem moved. I ended up fixing the problem by moving the div id'd as left to the first position and now it works every time.